# Invertir números dentro de un arreglo en Lenguaje C

Tags: c

Intento hacer que el contador **cant** aumente, y luego utilizar ese valor como condición.
Pero no me deja hacer nada. Podrían decirme en que me estoy equivocando?

```
int main(){
    int num;
    printf("Ingrese un numero; ");
    scanf("%i",&num);
    
    printf("La inversa del numero \"%i\" es: \"%i\"",num,inversa(num));
    
    return 0;
}

int inversa(int num){
    int cant=0,res,sum = 0,i,c;
    while(num!=0){
        num/=10;
        cant=cant+1;
    }

    for(i = 1;i <= cant;i++){
        res = num%10;
        num/=10;
        sum += (res * pow(10,cant-i));  
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Bienvenido a SO! Te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que ganes tu primera medalla. El problema que tienes en tú código es que cuando cuentas los digitos pierdes el número original (especificamente al hacer `num/=10;`) , con este ejemplo te lo demuestro utilizando una nueva variable (`num2`) para hacer la cuenta:

```
int main(){
    int num;
    printf("Ingrese un numero; ");
    scanf("%i",&num);
    
    printf("La inversa del numero \"%i\" es: \"%i\"",num,inversa(num));
    
    return 0;
}

int inversa(int num){
    int cant=0,res,sum = 0,i,c;
    int num2 = num;
    while(num2!=0){
        num2/=10;
        cant=cant+1;
    }

    for(i = 1;i <= cant;i++){
        res = num%10;
        num/=10;
        sum += (res * pow(10,cant-i));  
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya me sirvio, ya aprendi para futuros programas.